# Is it possible to spiritbond crafting gear in combat?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I have hit 60 in all my Disciples of Hand, and my materials to craft items to gain spiritbond on gear is rather on the low side. As the title says, is it faster or more efficient to get spiritbond from combat whilst wearing the Disciple of Hand gear?

And if so, what level mobs should I attack while wearing between level 55 and 60 gear?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind - I managed to figure out the answer (and it's super effective). Just participate in fate farming parties at appropriate level. Got 5% in 3 fates.

Ways to make this faster -

1. Non boss fates (monster wave fates)
2. meld basic materia into guarenteed slots of gear to be assimilated
3. purchase spiritbond potion from grand company
4. grand company spirit bond buff
5. Aetheryte rings should be equipped
6. Wear HQ gear

Comment: By chance, can you provide more information on the iLv of the gear and the Level for the FATEs?  Was there any Materia attached as well?

Comment: HQ gear, No materia attached (so it's slower). Wearing level 60 LHS gear, and 59, 58, 57 and 55 RHS gear. Asyz Lla fates (which is level 60 fates)

Comment: Oh, and I purchased a spiritbond potion from the FC